# Socket.IO socket disconnect event not fired when hard closing window

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I'm currently building chat rooms using Socket.io.
Everything works fine, it's pretty simple to use and well-documented.

The thing is if I reload the page, wait for socket trying to connect and then close the window before it is connected, the disconnect event for the socket is never fired.

This only occurs if I close the tab before the socket is connected but after the connection request has been sent.

As a result, I still appear online for others in the chat room while I just closed the tab.

Is there a way to timeout connections on the server ? So I can fire disconnect events for other users if the socket isn't active anymore ?

Comment: Sockets that are not closed gracefully often hang around like this.  Two common workarounds are to either send periodic traffic over the socket (a keep-alive/ping) and close it in event of an error, or set the raw TCP socket options to do this for you.  You can read more at http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/05/detection-of-half-open-dropped.html

Comment: Thank you buddy, great article. I digged a bit deeper and found out that Socket.io is already implementing this : the problem is that the socket closed before I put a 'disconnect' listener on it. I've solved it by checking the underlying connection readyState (which was set on 'closed') and firing myself the event. Thanks for your answer. it's still very informative, looking forward switching to a lower-lever library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I digged a bit deeper and found out that Socket.io is already implementing this : the problem is that the socket closed before I put a 'disconnect' listener on it. I've solved it by checking the underlying connection readyState (which was set on 'closed') and firing myself the event. – whitep4nther